# Code signing certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, code-signing, electron

We recently launched a software application built using electron where the app does check a firebase database upon launch of the app and for some reason, it was triggering the Norton Antivirus firewall due to it connecting to firestore DB (Firebase.)  We proceeded to contact SSL.com where we purchased the EV Code Signing Cert. and they said we also needed the OV Signing Cert. Well, now we have both and also paying 150/mo for cloud signing on top of the $300+ for the EV Code Signing per year). Something doesn't add up.

Do we really need two signing certificates so we don't trigger any antivirus during the installation of our application on Windows? Does this seem normal for Code signing to be charged monthly? Perhaps the token on a USB would eliminate this expense?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a Organization Validation certificate and an Extended Validation Code Signing Certificate? Only one would be used to signed the certificate, the other likely the OV certificate, would be used to make secure connections to the database.  Technically neither of them are required if you don't require the executable to be signed or the secure connection to be automatically trusted by the operating system. **Here is something you won't hear, neither a OV or a EV, will prevent an AV product from flagging your application.**

Comment: It does not make sense you would be paid monthly for either a EV or a OV certificate, as they are typically valid between 1 and 2 years.  However, I can't discount the fact, you might be paying for the certificate overtime, of course that does not make sense, since they are valid the minute they are created.  So something else must be going on, but what that is with regards to your monthly payments, we can't help you with.

Comment: Yes, correct, the OV was necessary after the link to the database was flagged in the Norton Firewall. After we installed the OV Norton accepted and no triggers happened so it worked perfectly while installing. In our case Norton and Windows Defender were satisfied with the installation of the certs as they were triggered prior to using them.  I guess what I need more clarification on is the main difference between signing the Certificate using a USB and Cloud Singing Service? I guess the token is stored on the cloud vs a USB device, hence the cost per month?

Comment: That is likely a question you should be asking SSL.com; Yes, it appears the difference, is how you are delivered the certificate. I am not familiar with SSL.com business model. However, it makes sense you need both a Code Signing EV certificate for the executable and a separate SSL certificate to the database connection.

Comment: None of these code signing certificates guarantee your software not triggering AV software in my experience.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - As you correctly point out, the executable being signed, won't prevent a third-party AV from treating it as a false positive.  An executable being signed will prevent Windows, from displaying the warning about a unknown publisher, and perhaps asking for confirmation if the user wants to run the executable (SmartScreen).  However, the reputation of the file will also take a part, in if warnings will be displayed or not displayed.  Having your executable being signed is obviously a positive thing. You will see less restrictions imposed on systems with increased security.

Comment: Upon more research, the fee of 150/ month was for using the cloud signing (proprietary) tool that SSL.com provides for EV signing and basically uploads your token to the cloud. To avoid these monthly fees you have to use a FIPS USB device that stores the token. I must have missed this when I purchased the EV.  They give you 25 days to use the cloud signing for free. It was not until after the first month with just building 9 times that we got stuck with an additional monthly fee. Doing it again I would go with Sectigo for EV Code Signing Cert and get the USB token as part of the purchase.

Comment: @Ramhound Installing the EV code signing cert was the only way we were able to get all the PCs we tested our install on not to trigger Norton firewall.  Prior to using the EV cert, it would not install without prompting you to trust the app first. I would strongly recommend using one.